# some questions from a node.js newbie

Tags: node.js

i have just started learning node and i am using node-v0.4.11 on Fedora 12. It installed without any errors and i am able to run some basic programs but there are some things i cant figure out

> If i create a server at a port and then if i stop node using *Ctrl+C*
>   i cannot use that port again for starting a server without restarting
>   the system.

my code looks like this

```
var port=8080;
var count=0;
var http=require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  count++;
  console.log('request no '+count+' received');
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('you are at port '+port);
  });
server.listen(port);
console.log('server started at port '+port);
```

Now when i save the file and execute it the server starts. But when i stop the server  from the shell , i cannot start the server again at the port i started before(in this case port *8080*).This is bad because every time i have to make changes in that file i have to change the port number too.Can i stop this behavior?

**EDIT:**

This is the error that i get when i try to start the server at the same port again

```
Server started at 8080

node.js:203
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net_uv.js:557:11)
    at Array.<anonymous> (net_uv.js:632:28)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:195:26)
```

i saw the process list after i terminated `node` using `Ctrl+C` and i found node was still running. So i killed it and checked the process list again to make sure it was dead and it was(i could not see it in the process list). Now i again tried to start the server at the same port but i got the same error as above.And once i stop the server and make request from the browser the request hangs up for ever(it keeps on waiting).

---

> My next problem is that in the above when the server starts and i make
>   the first request `count` is incremented 3 times and i can see 3
>   messages at the console. This is just for the first request,if i make
>   more requests `count` is just incremented once. Whats wrong?
>
> *this problem is solved*

---

> My next problem is that if i change `res.writeHead(200);` to
>   `res.writeHead(404);` or any other valid status code like `300` node
>   gives error at the command line but these are valid status codes and
>   the server should start and respond to each request according the
>   status code like `Not found` for `404`. What am i doing wrong?
>
> *this problem is solved*

---

> I am not able to use `Firebug`'s 'Net' tab to monitor requests when i
>   send requests to the server created by Node. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks for bearing.

Comment: strange...  I dropped in the exact same code and am not having any of those issues...  is that everything that is running?

Comment: `But when i terminate node from the shell , i cannot start the server again at the port i started before` how are you doing this? You should try rebooting and trying again on 8080 ;)

Comment: @jcolebrand φ thats what i have to do and i dont understand why.I am terminating the node process from shell and that should free the port. if it does not can i free that port without rebooting?

Comment: Are you sure you're using ctrl-c and not ctrl-z?

Comment: @david i was using ctrl-z. how stupid of me. Using `Ctrl-C` solves everything.Apologies to everyone who wasted their time

Comment: @lovesh ;) ~ I knew, that's why I suggested rebooting and asking "how" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i cannot start the server again at the port i started before

You should not be seeing this behavior, and I cannot reproduce it. Do you get an error message when you try to start the server again? What is it? Once you've stopped the server, do you see any `node` processes in your process list? If so, can you start your server after you kill them?

---

> `count` is incremented 3 times and i can see 3 messages at the console

Your browser is sending multiple requests. For example, in Chrome, you might get (1) a pre-fetch request (where Chrome downloads the page it *thinks* you want), (2) the actual page request, and (3) a request for `favicon.ico`; your Node app is listening for *all* requests, not just requests to the `/` URL. After the initial request, the browser caches the favicon, etc. and doesn't need to request them again.

Try adding `console.log(req.url);` to your callback and see what URLs the browser is asking for.

---

> any other valid status code like `300` node gives error at the command line

I can't reproduce this problem. What error are you receiving?

---

> I am not able to use Firebug's 'Net' tab to monitor requests when i send requests to the server created by Node

I'm also not able to reproduce this. Firebug and other client-side debugging tools don't know or care what technology is running on the server; it just speaks HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question to include the error for my first problem.And i checked that why count was incrementing 3 times i found that `Firefox` was sending 2 requests for `favicon.icon` which i think is because when it ,makes the request the 1st time it does not get the icon so tries once more. But i didnt get the `pre-fetch` thing you said for chrome. why does the browser makes a guess what i want? And yes even i dont understand why firebug does not catch requests made to node. After all they are http requests.

Comment: By the way, you probably meant ```favicon.ico``` not ```.icon``` :)

Comment: Chrome has a new-ish feature where after you start to type a URL it goes ahead and downloads the page before you hit enter. Just another attempt to try to make things "faster." @Tom Indeed! Fingers are faster than the brain. :) Thanks.